# ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom is creating shadow dom but not encapsulating component from external css

Tags: angular

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1phjqd?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

I have a simplest possible angular component. The only difference is that I have `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` enabled. Doing this is creating `shadow dom` as expected. But its not protecting component from external styling.

For example I have following styles in `style.css`

```
*{
  font-size: 30px;
  color:red;
}
```

This style is being applied to `div`s inside the component.

Can someone please advice, why?

Comment: Your problem is when you use `* {} ` or unprotected style by encapsulation? they are different.

Comment: My understanding is, no external style should apply on shadow DOM. Is that incorrect?

Comment: None of the code inside a shadow DOM can affect anything outside it, allowing for handy encapsulation and none of the code outside a shadow DOM can affect anything inside it.but * is different.